# JS: Why I can not send a value from onclick?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="alink('http://www.youtube.com/v/1a0E5BuvZ28&feature=youtube_gdata?fs=1&hl=en')">vedio1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="alink('http://www.youtube.com/v/A6X01URCHZY&feature=youtube_gdata?fs=1&hl=en')">vedio2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="alink('http://www.youtube.com/v/SNaJ0SYvcYA&feature=youtube_gdata?fs=1&hl=en')">vedio3</a></li>
  <object width="600" height="320"><param name="movie" id="id" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/oyzmXMfHIeI&feature=youtube_gdata?fs=1&hl=it"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed id="src" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/oyzmXMfHIeI&feature=youtube_gdata?fs=1&hl=en" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="600" height="320"></embed></object>
  <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    function alink($value)
    {
      document.getElementById('id').value = $value;
      document.getElementById('src').src = $value;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want make a custom list of youtube vedio. I use javascript code. Why I can not send a value from onclick? It show fault: document.getElementById(...)' null...Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me - but only on Firefox

Comment: Any special reason for the `defer`?

Comment: What does this mean: "It show fault: document.getElementById(...)' null..."?

Comment: Random thought: Take off the sigil ($). This isn't Perl or PHP.

Comment: @pst: Sigils are completely valid within variable names in JS (see jQuery, Prototype, …)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel It's not about being a 'technically valid construct'. It is about *doing the right thing.* EMCAScript Ed.3 specifies "The dollar sign is intended for use only in
mechanically generated code." (This clause is removed from Ed.5 -- however, this doesn't mean "go use it willy-nilly"). I find jQuery an appropriate use, for instance. In this case though -- no. It's not needed, adds no value (if anything it introduces inconsistencies), and should likely be removed unless there is a good reason for it.

Comment: Hello:I test in ie8. so It show fault: document.getElementById(...)' null..."
I think maybe the flash load slower caused the value can not put in, so I add defer

Comment: @yuli: Can you copy & paste the actual error message? I don't think you've given us all of it, considering that your quotes are unpaired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the major browsers, only Firefox lets you dynamically change the source of an embedded flash movie. For this reason, your code will not work in Internet Explorer, Chrome, or Safari (or rather, it will change the source, but to no effect). To get it to work in all browsers, you have to completely rewrite the embedded object to the DOM, in its entirety.

The easiest way to do this is to use the [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) javascript library. This library not only encapsulates all the functionality to make it very easy to use, but also ensures cross-browser compatibility and deals with edge cases (like if the browser does not have flash installed).

Comment: Oh, mama mia...I'll try to learn swfobject javascript library. And if it possible, would you like to give me a related Tutorials? That I can learn easily. English is not my major language...Thanks

Comment: @user499587, follow the link I posted to swfobject and click "documentation". Right at the top of the documentation are links for translated versions for many languages.

Comment: Hello @Ben Lee. I download the files, I open the index.html, it also can not use my method. Can you teach me more?